# Alternative of IN keyword of SQL in Siebel Server scripting for search spec?

Tags: sql, vbscript, siebel, escript

Does anyone know how can we filter BC results based on multiple values in search specification? 
As `IN` keyword in SQL ?
something like:

```
bc.SetSearchExpr("[Id] in ('a','b','c')");
```

Or use of `OR` operator is the only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use `IN` in Siebel, it's not a [valid search operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/ToolsDevRef/ToolsDevRef_Operators19.html). But at least, you can simplify your expression by using a search specification instead of a search expression. These two lines do exactly the same:

```js
bc.SetSearchExpr("[Id]='a' or [Id]='b' or [Id]='c'");

bc.SetSearchSpec("Id", "='a' OR ='b' OR ='c'");
```

Note that you can't use both `SetSearchSpec` and `SetSearchExpr` methods [simultaneously](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/OIRef/OIRefInterfaceRef127.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR like this:

```
bc.SetSearchExpr("[Id] = 'a' or [Id] ='b' or [Id] ='c')");
```

but I think using `IN` is better than using `OR`.

Other than using `IN` or `OR` you dont have any option.

Comment: So, `IN` keyword can be used in Siebel like I wrote ?

Comment: Siebel didnt recognize `IN` keyword in this function :(

Comment: @Reminisce:- Did you try using the OR query which I wrote?

Comment: `OR` works, I mentioned it actually in my post. The reason I don't want to use it is, it requires copying the field name everytime for different values. So I was just asking is there a way to avoid this duplications.

Comment: @Reminisce:- I am afraid that there is no IN statement in Siebel. You have to use the OR.